# Проксирование куки nginx

Tags: nginx, cookie, proxy, redirect, proxypass

Перевожу свои приложения на докер. Я имею 4 томката в контейнерах на машине, висят просто на разных портах, и nginx тоже в контейнере, стандартная балансировка.

Как правильно прописать проброс куки, чтобы не было ситуации, что я захожу авторизироваться на сайт, и после авторизации он меня перекидывает на другой томкат опять к странице авторизации, тем самым я не могу пройти дальше авторизации?

Если в nginx оставить один upstream, то все работает корректно. Я думаю что дело в печеньках =)

[image: nginx.conf]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Так у вас проблема не в проксировании куки, а в том что разные сервера tomcat ничего не знают друг о друге. И, соответственно нужно либо чинить эту проблему, либо «приклеивать» пользователя к определённому серверу. Для второго в платной версии nginx есть https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky (ну или можно поискать бесплатный модуль или вообще написать на lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам решение случайно, в блок upstream достаточно дописать
ip_hash;
Все заработало, может кому пригодиться. Всем спасибо и удачи =)